# If record exist in A then return record else if record exist in B return record else null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to express this idea in SQL

```
If record exist in A then return record else if record exist in B return record ELSE NULL
```

Example: Select the team captain if they exists else select the oldest player on the team

```
WITH Captains_CTE (TeamName, PlayerName)
AS (
    SELECT TeamName, PlayerName FROM TeamPlayer WHERE IsCaptain = 1
), 
OldestPlayer_CTE (TeamName, PlayerName)
AS (
    SELECT TeamName, PlayerName FROM TeamPlayer AS tp
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT TeamName, MAX(PlayerAge) AS MaxAge
        FROM TeamPlayer 
        GROUP BY TeamName
    ) AS old ON old.TeamName = tp.TeamName AND old.MaxAge = tp.PlayerAge

)
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN Captains_CTE.TeamName IS NULL THEN OldestPlayer_CTE.TeamName
            ELSE Captains_CTE.TeamName 
        END AS TeamName,
        CASE 
            WHEN Captains_CTE.PlayerName IS NULL THEN OldestPlayer_CTE.PlayerName
            ELSE Captains_CTE.PlayerName 
        END AS PlayerName
FROM Captains_CTE
FULL OUTER JOIN OldestPlayer_CTE ON Captains_CTE.TeamName = OldestPlayer_CTE.TeamName
```

I can do this by doing a outer join on A and B and then building a CASE statement for each column I wish to return but there has to be a better way. (yes my example query makes some terrible assumptions about age being unique)

Comment: I have no idea what the code has to do with the question.  Nothing in the code is called `a` or `b`, for instance.

Comment: You could use `COALESCE()` to simplify the `CASE`, but that's just a side note. My actual answer is below.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The team captain code is just an example I thought up rather posting my really monstrous 50 line ERP queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
union all
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.? = b.?);  -- "?" is for the column that specifies whether the record exists in A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APPLY` to do this:

```
SELECT t.TeamName, coalsesce(captain.PlayerName,'') As Captain
FROM Teams t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName
   FROM TeamPlayers tp
   WHERE tp.TeamID = t.TeamID
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN tp.IsCaptain = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
        PlayerAge DESC
) captain
```

If there isn't a `Teams` table (there *ought* to be if there's any sense to the schema at all, but you never know), you can derive one:

```
SELECT t.TeamName, coalsesce(captain.PlayerName,'') As Captain
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TeamName FROM TeamPlayers) t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 PlayerName
   FROM TeamPlayers tp
   WHERE tp.TeamName = t.TeamName 
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN tp.IsCaptain = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
        PlayerAge DESC
) captain
```